# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xc4'

Tags: python, eclipse, import

Problem while importing module

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import win32com.client
```

when I run it in eclipse, `syntaxError` occurs.

but it runs perfectly on Windows console.

how to type the right coding of pywin32?

Answer (score 1):

For eclipse unicode console support:

1. Add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to eclipse.ini which is in the eclipse install directory.
2. In eclipse – Run\Run Configurations\Python Run\configuration\Common\make sure UTF-8 is selected
3. In eclipse – Window\Preferences\General\Workspace\Text file encoding\making sure UTF-8 is selected
4. In [python install path]\Lib\site.py – chane from encoding = “ascii” to encoding = “utf-8”
5. Make sure you’re using unicode supporting fonts in eclipse – Window\Preferences\Appearance\Colors and Fonts\Debug\Console font\Edit